# How reliable is AUTO_INCREMENT in a transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions, auto-increment

I am planning on using auto-incremented user IDs on my website. As user data will be split across several tables, I was wondering, how reliable are auto-incremented values in transactions, i.e. when inserting some initial values into tables in a transaction upon registration, is it safe to just let the auto-incrementor set the IDs in all the tables or should it just insert into one table, get the inserted ID in a separate query and use it in the subsequent insertions, resulting in higher database load just for user creation?

Comment: Define "reliable". It's physically impossible to insert duplicate primary keys but your multiple-statement alternative requires very careful table locking.

Comment: The biggest challenge with auto increment id's is if you have multiple environments and need to keep ID's in sync between them for same valued rows.  Like in a lookup table.  Otherwise they generally work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto increment field gets reserved everytime you are attempting to insert something. The insert more or less proceeds in 2 steps:

1: reserve the next available auto-increment key
2: perform the insert with this reserved key

Now, if the transaction rolls back, the only thing that can never be rolled back is the auto-increment reservation, resulting in gaps in the auto-increment column. Because of this, if you are trying to predict 100% what the auto increment will be, it is impossible to do so. There is no other issue with auto_increment that i know of, and in almost all cases, it is more reliable to rely on mysql's features than to try to do something manually.

Answer (score 0):

If your insertions happen under very controlled conditions, like there are no concurrent transactions, and nothing is ever rolled back, you might be safe. Otherwise, the answer could depend on what storage engine you are using. You should expect `auto_increment` to result in gaps in the numbering at [least if you are using InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html).

More generally, every DB I know has the chance of gaps in `auto_increment` (or the equivalent) values. The reason is that if it were not so, any transaction inserting a new row would have to block all other insertions to that table. This is because a second row can't be inserted when it's not possible to know what the next value will be if the first transaction hasn't yet committed or rolled back. If you allow gaps, then you just assume the first transaction will commit, and if it happens to rollback, you have a gap, but that's not a problem.

If your concern is high load for a user creation operation, you might be able to make things snappier by implementing the function as a stored procedure; this way you can avoid round-tripping back to the application for each query.

Comment: Please note that gaps are by no means an issue.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: I think they are, if you are trying to predict what numbers were generated, which seems to be what the question is about.